# ElasticSearch get next and previous document id from current id

Tags: elasticsearch, search

Searching from last 6 hour but not got any solution. Please help me.
Elasticsearch id are: 2, 4, 7, 8, 11, 15, 16, 19, ....

I have current document id 11, then how to get next id as 15 and previous id as 8.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can run two queries, one for the next ID and one for previous ID.

The query for the next ID is:

```
GET /<index>/_search
{
  "_source": [
    "id"
  ],
  "query": {
    "range": {
      "id": {
        "gt": 11
      }
    }
  },
  "sort": [
    {
      "id": {
        "order": "asc"
      }
    }
  ],
  "size": 1
}
```

and the query for the previous ID is:

```
GET /<index>/_search
{
  "_source": [
    "id"
  ],
  "query": {
    "range": {
      "id": {
        "lt": 11
      }
    }
  },
  "sort": [
    {
      "id": {
        "order": "desc"
      }
    }
  ],
  "size": 1
}
```

Comment: Thanks, Great! Working Fine.